# css padding-right clear element on input EmulateIE8 mode

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a strange behavior on input field.
Using IE10 and IE11 with **META HTTP-EQUIV="X-UA-Compatible" CONTENT="IE=EmulateIE8"**.
I try to add padding: 0px 10px; property to an input tag in order to move the X to the left.
When checking in development tools F12, it seems that padding is there (orange blocks in input), but X is still appears on the right. It should be appearing to the left of the orange block.
Any ideas why it happens and how to handle it?

Comment: Have you tried it with a native environment? Sometimes the emulation is not 100% perfect, in particular with some CSS styling.

Comment: Hi Marco, when you say native environment, what do you refer to?

Comment: I mean a WindowsXP (either Vista) machine with IE8.

Comment: It only appears in Windows7, 8.1 and with IE10, IE11. In IE8 there is no "X". I guess this feature was represented by Microsoft only in IE10 and up.

Comment: Sorry I've misunderstood the issue.